# How to change cell value down one column into another but change the row value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, html, microsoft-excel-2016

```
    <figure>
  <img src="https://laptopscreenz.com/wp-content/uploads/156-WUXGA-40PIN-FHD.jpg" title="=(B3)" alt="=(B3)" "longdesc="=(B3)">
  <figcaption>=(B3)</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="https://laptopscreenz.com/wp-content/uploads/156-WUXGA-40PIN-FHD-2.jpg" title="Innolux BT156GW02 V.0 Laptop LCD Screen Replacement 15.6" alt="Innolux BT156GW02 V.0 Laptop LCD Screen Replacement 15.6" "longdesc="Innolux BT156GW02 V.0 Laptop LCD Screen Replacement 15.6">
  <figcaption>Innolux BT156GW02 V.0 Laptop LCD Screen Replacement 15.6"</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="https://laptopscreenz.com/wp-content/uploads/156-WUXGA-40PIN-FHD-3.jpg" title="Innolux BT156GW02 V.0 Laptop LCD Screen Replacement 15.6" alt="Innolux BT156GW02 V.0 Laptop LCD Screen Replacement 15.6" "longdesc="=(B2)">
  <figcaption>=(b2)</figcaption>
</figure>
```

---

I'm using excel and I even have the kutools extension.
I have this html snippet that i need to copy down thousands of cells, lets say im using an empty column , lets go with G how would I get the value of the contents whenever it refers to cell B2 in this snippet and furthermore when copied down column G how can I change the B2 instances to B3 , B4 , B5 , etc..

Pardon my ignorance there just so many features I'm just trying to be efficient because its tons of data to be created..
Thank you very much in advance for anyone that can offer help!

Comment: Do you also want to change the B3 instances to B4, B5, B6, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Sorry for the misunderstanding.  I think I understand your problem now. You still need to break up the text at the locations where you want to insert the content from Column B.  I counted four places in your screenshot, and divided the text like this:

[image]

I put these in `D14:D18`, but you can put them wherever you need to.

Now all you have to do is concatenate everything together using `&`:

`=D$14&B2&D$15&B2&D$16&B2&D$17&B2&D$18`

and you'll get these results:

[image]

The ampersands concatenate the nine sections, and `B2` changes to `B3, B4,` etc. as the formula is filled down. Note the `$`'s in the Column D references.  That prevents them from changing as the formula is filled down.

I hope this helps, and good luck.

Comment: The B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 etc is what i wan to replace with the contents in the corresponding cells.....

Comment: The B column is already populated down 1225 cells down with info in each B cell, I"m trying to get the content from the B cells to match any column with the same row of B cell contect

Comment: http://prntscr.com/j98gvw

Comment: check the screen shot above ^

Comment: Now I get it. This isn't hard, and I'll edit the answer tomorrow.

Comment: Pretty pathetic losers on here downvote something they can't answer.  Get a life/job.